# Using third-party JS libraries in Mozilla Add-On SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, bdd, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm starting a new project (Firefox add-on) and I'd like to try using behavior-driven development. I particularly like the Jasmine BDD library. However, I can't find a good way how to use a framework such as Jasmine in the Add-On SDK.

One problem is that Jasmine needs setTimeout (and similar) functions to be specified on the global object, whereas Add-On SDK exports those using "timers" module. But let's say I tweak Jasmine to get those object from "timers" (or add the the methods exported by timers to the global object).

The bigger problem is that I don't know how to actually run the tests. There is a test directory generated by the SDK, however, there's no window or document object there to allow me to see the output (and I'd really like to see the fancy HTML output). I guess I could create a content script that would modify the page, but then I can't access (test) the background script.

Have you ever faced this before? Is there any recommended way how to deal with that?

Thanks!
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Add-on SDK windows API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/windows.html) to open a new window to run your tests in. You should be able to load the Jasmine script(s) with the [subscript loader](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/mozIJSSubScriptLoader) and set window and document to whatever you want in the scope of that subscript:

```
var windows = require("windows").browserWindows;

windows.open({
  url: "about:blank",
  onOpen: function(window) {
    var script;
      var scriptLoader = Cc["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].
        getService(Ci.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
      scriptLoader.loadSubScript(subscriptSpec, script);
      script["window"] = window;
      script["document"] = window.document;
      // ... run your tests here by calling script.someFunc() ...
   }
});
```

**Update:** Further research shows that the browserWindows are actually special wrappers that don't give you access to the content window. You might try getting a window/document from a [hidden frame](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/api-utils/docs/hidden-frame.html). That's the only way I can see to get access to an HTML document from privileged code.